# Confirmar cadastro pelo email - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estou tentando fazer uma confirmação de cadastro por email, porém não estou tendo êxito. Consigo pegar o usuario, email e senha. porém quando dou um 'echo' na variavel $id e $md5 para conferir os dados não aparece nada e o INSERT não é feito. Segue o codigo.

```
<?php
$host = "mysql:busca;host=localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$pass = "";

try{
    $pdo = new PDO($host, $usuario, $pass);
}catch(PDOExecption $e){
    echo "Falha: ". $e->getMessage();
}

$user = addcslashes($_POST['user'],"F");
$email = addcslashes($_POST['email'],"F");
$senha = md5(addcslashes($_POST['senha'],"F"));

$pdo->query("INSERT INTO tabela1 SET user='$user', email='$email', senha='$senha'");

$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
$md5 = md5($id);

$assunto = "Confirme seu cadastro";
$link = "confirma.php?h=".$md5;
$mensagem = '<a href="'.$link.'">Clique aqui para confirmar: </a>';
$header = "From: teste";

echo $user.'<br>';
echo $email.'<br>';
echo $senha.'<br>';
echo $id.'<br>';
echo $md5.'<br>';
mail($email, $assunto, $mensagem, $header);


?>
```

Tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabela1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `user` varchar(50),
  `email` varchar(100),
  `senha` varchar(50),
  `status` tinyint(4)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa linha está incorreta

```
$host = "mysql:busca;host=localhost";
```

o correto é

```
$host = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=busca";
```